# Validation of missing data

Tags: excel-formula

I need to come up with a validation in a summary sheet of excel. The validation will display the cell reference ( not value) from a column in another excel worksheet. The validation is simple enough: Check column A - rows 1 to 100. If these are non-blank, then column B - rows 1 to 100 also need to be non-blank; in case any cell in column B is blank then return the cell reference to the summary sheet.
In case Column A ( any of the rows ) is blank, then column B also should be blank.

Thanks.

Comment: So... what *have* you come up with so far...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a formula that should do exactly what your asking for, unless I misunderstood the question. It assumes your data starts in Sheet1 cell A1.

```
=IF(AND(OR(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$A1),ISNA(Sheet1!$A1)),AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$B1)),NOT(ISNA(Sheet1!$B1)))),"B"&ROW(Sheet1!$B1),IF(AND(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$A1)),NOT(ISNA(Sheet1!$A1))),OR(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$B1),(ISNA(Sheet1!$B1)))),"B"&ROW(Sheet1!$B1),"Valid"))
```

I tested this and it works fine. Tailor it to work with your workbook and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: WOW ! @BobbitWormJoe - your code is bang on: It is exactly what I was looking for ! Thanks a lot !